# Kinematics CAD package for LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

Do any good libraries exist for drawing kinematics diagram in LaTeX.

I am looking for something similar to the following image.

[image: Kinematics diagram]

Answer (score 2):

For your question I think that your question have a solution using `sketch-lib` that is a 3D solids library for [sketch](http://alexdu.github.io/sketch-lib/) (where at the bottom of the page you can find the useful resources).

The files have an extension `.sk` (sketch) and it is possible to use language `TikZ` in global options section.

Here you can find an old guide: http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/sketch.pdf

For my opinion it is very hard to understand for me. Related links:

1. http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/graphics/sketch/Doc/sketch.html#Introduction-by-example
2. http://alexdu.github.io/sketch-lib/ where you find the same image of your question

[image]

with the source: `kinematics.sk`.